# Callback return the response but when send in API response shows Blank in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, body-parser

I have to send a response using REST API. Callback return the exact response but when I pass it into the API response, it shows me Blank.

Here's the code:

```
getAuctionListingByType(filterData, function(response) {
  console.log('auction listing');
  console.log(response);
  res.json({
    code: 200,
    message: 'Auction',
    data: response
  });
});
```

Console shows the below response:

```
 [[auction_id: '3',title: 'Salvage Auction 2011',business: 'Insurance'],
 [auction_id: '4',title: 'Salvage Auction 2013',business: 'Bank']]
```

But when i hit the API the response is:

```
{"code":200,"message":"Auction","data":[[],[]]}
```

When I console the response it prints, but when I pass to client it is blank.

Comment: Guess.. You should have `array of object` not `array of arrays`..Browser will fail to interpret  it..

Comment: Please include more of the server side setup. It looks like from above you have no access to "res" variable in this function. Please include the routing method for the server that hits this function.

Comment: @AaronFranco : i have used the proper express framework for req and res.

Comment: @RayonDabre: It works :) Thanks Buddy :)

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response should be in array of objects format instead of array format.

Your Response should be like this:

```
[{auction_id: '3',title: 'Salvage Auction 2011',business: 'Insurance'},{auction_id: '4',title: 'Salvage Auction 2013',business: 'Bank'}]
```

change the format of your response to array of objects.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending `array of arrays` from server but your `array` is invalid.

> *[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.*

You are treating `object` as `array`

Response should look like:

> `[{auction_id: '3',title: 'Salvage Auction 2011',business: 'Insurance'},{auction_id: '4',title: 'Salvage Auction 2013',business: 'Bank'}];`

*Note:* Check console(`cmd`) for errors, you might see **`Unexpected token :`**

Answer (score 0):

Store the response in a variable and pass that variable in api.

```
       getAuctionListingByType(filterData, function(response) {
              console.log('auction listing');
              console.log(response);
              var TempStore=response;
             res.json({
                   code: 200,
                   message: 'Auction',
                  data: TempStore
                  });
             });
```